# GStreamer clock-rate=(int)48000 issue

Tags: udp, gstreamer, clock, multicast, rate

I try to playout udp multicast audio stream.

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc multicast-group=239.192.31.65 port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)2,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)96,clock-rate=(int)44100,encoding-name=(string)L24" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=10 ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false async=false
```

It works but audio plays slower than original stream due to wrong samplerate. Original stream samplerate is 48kHz. But if I try to set it, GStreamer quits with error.

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe udpsrc multicast-group=239.192.31.65 port=5004 caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)2,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)96,clock-rate=(int)48000,encoding-name=(string)L24" ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=10 ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false async=false
```

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>  Pipeline is live and does not need
>   PREROLL ...
>  Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
>  New clock:
>   GstSystemClock
>  ERROR: from element
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream
>   error.
>  Additional debug info:
>  gstbasesrc.c(3055):
>   gst_base_src_loop ():
>   
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
>  streaming stopped,
>   reason not-negotiated (-4)
>  Execution ended after
>   0:00:00.018626636
>  Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>  Setting
>   pipeline to READY ...
>  Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>  Freeing
>   pipeline ...

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't believe - the problem was in soundcard settings - as soon as I set 48000 in soundcard setting in windows settings it start working!

[image: soundcard windows settings]